# document.getElementById('xxx') showing null

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Here is my JS

```
var linkArray = {
    boothsizeDiv_link: false,
    furnishingsprovidedDiv_link: false,
    electricalDiv_link: false,
    rentalfurnishingsDiv_link: false,
    gesgraphicsDiv_link: false,
    geslaborDiv_link: false,
    contractorDiv_link: false,
    carpetingDiv_link: false,
    boothlightingDiv_link: false,
    javitsDiv_link: false,
    boothsealDiv_link: false,
    mannequinsDiv_link: false,
    calcDiv_link: false
};
for (var i in linkArray) {

    if (linkArray['boothsizeDiv_link'] == false) {

        document.getElementById('jumplinks').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('boothsizeDiv_link').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

html is

```
<div id="jumplinks" align="left" style="display:none;">

 <div id="boothsizeDiv_link" style="display:none;"><a href="#" onclick="ToggleLinks('boothsizeDiv');"><font face="calibri">BOOTHSIZE</font></a></div>

</div>
```

And in my html file there is div with id `jumplinks` with `style='display:none;'`
When I try to run the JS file, it is saying like `document.getElementById('jumplinks')` is `null`.
What is the problem? Need help..

Comment: Could you post your html? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: Why are you iterating through `linkArray`? You are not using any of its values or variables.

Comment: This jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/WDPms/2/ shows how position/timing of your javascript will affect things.

Comment: place your script after div elements

Comment: One more thing how to find out length of the array 'linkArray'???

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't need to iterate through linkArray to find its length. Use linkArray.length to find the array length. Maybe:

```
console.log("linkArray length is: " + linkArray.length);
```

Concerning the null error, could you also tell us where you are calling the javascript? You could encompass the JS in a function in the head, and call that function from elsewhere. The following code also acts as a toggle, allowing you to hide the divs as well:

```
<script>

function togLinks() {
    if (linkArray['boothsizeDiv_link'] == false) {

        var jumplinks = document.getElementById('jumplinks');
        var boothsizeDiv_link = document.getElementById('boothsizeDiv_link');

        jumplinks.style.display = jumplinks.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";
        boothsizeDiv_link.style.display = boothsizeDiv_link.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";
    }
}

</script>
```

Calling toglinks:

```
<div onclick="togLinks()">show/hide links</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should only execute Javascript afte the DOM has finished loading, so the above will only work after the `document.ready` event has fired. If you run your code in the `<head>` of a page, it is run before the element actually exists, and hence it is `null`.

Here's an example with plain Javascript for hooking into that event :
[$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WDPms/ is says the object is `null` as well, even though it is `undefined`. Depends on how you do your logging on what is reported (of course it's undefined, but functions as `alert` will report `null` and I don't know what he used to test his object).